# Get notification with NotificationManager by any tag or id

Tags: java, android

In my app, I am required to detect a specific notification from the notification bar and open some intent if the notification is detected.  I know there is a method of activeNotifications of notificationManager I want to do this in API below 23.Is there any way to identify the notification from the notification bar?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()` to get all current notifications.

As per Documentation:

> public `StatusBarNotification[] getActiveNotifications ()` Recover a
>   list of active notifications: ones that have been posted by the
>   calling app that have not yet been dismissed by the user or
>   `cancel(String, int)`ed by the app. Each notification is embedded in a
>   StatusBarNotification object, including the original tag and id
>   supplied to `notify()` (via `getTag()` and `getId()`) as well as a copy of
>   the original Notification object (via
>   `StatusBarNotification.getNotification()`).

and its available from API Level 23

Refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#getActiveNotifications()

Comment: but I want to detect notifications in API < 23. would you like to suggest me a way for API below 23.

Comment: did you find ? @AliHamzaIub13